# Strange behaviour with PayPal IPN involving online store package names

Tags: php, laravel-5, paypal-ipn

Lately we have received error below:

local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object'

I know why this error is happening. We have an online store that works with PayPal-IPN.

In our database - we will have the item name Example "Generic Item Name Package 1 $30"

The issue lately is when we go to the checkout page on paypal, it is adding '+' symbols for spaces. so it will be "Generic+Item+Name+Package+1+$30". So this is what it is trying to find in our database and throwing the error.

The strange thing is that this is intermittent and only recently started (we havent made any changes to our system) We can proceed to the checkout on the same package a few times, some times it displays the package without '+' and thus it correctly works and updates in our database. Others it doesnt.

See screenshot

[image: Package]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question is un-answered, the problem as been solved.

It was an issue on PayPal's end which has since been fixed.